# Angular $resource endpoint with two parameters

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-resource, angular-services

I've got a setup using a service to handle $resource that is as follows:

**Service**

```
factory('EventSlot', ['$resource', function ($resource){
    return $resource('/api/events/:id/slots/:slotId', {id: "@Id", slotId: "@slotId"},
    {
        signup: {
           method: 'PUT'
        }
     });
 }]);
```

**Calling Function**

```
EventSlot.signup({id: $scope.id, slotId: $scope.signUpSlot.id}, $scope.signUpSlot);
```

However, when the PUT call actually goes through it goes through to the endpoint:
`/api/events/123/slots/` where 123 is the appropriate `@Id` however `@slotId` never gets attached.  So, what I want is `/api/events/123/slots/456` but that never happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the logic works as expected and the possible reason why it was not working is because `$scope.signUpSlot.id` may be `undefined`.

I created a demo and you can open the browser console and see the call is actually made to the correct url:

```
PUT http://fiddle.jshell.net/api/events/123/slots/456 404 (NOT FOUND)
```

<kbd>**[Demo on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rv9qN/)**</kbd>

Comment: That did seem to be the problem.  I wasn't making sure it was declared beforehand.  Thanks!